# Label in ListViewDataItem setting property affects all labels

Tags: asp.net

I have a listview called "lvQuestions" which has a label (called `lblMissingField`) on it and a couple of other fields.  When the user tries to postback the page, I call a routine that first sets ALL `lvlMissingField.Text = string.empty` and then validates that "the other" fields in the ListViewDataItem have been filled in.  If they haven't been filled I set the particular listview's `lvlMissingField.Text = "*"` to visually mark them with a "*" (Note: standard asp.net validators are not used).

So, what happens?  Every lblMissingField.Visible is displayed, what am I missing here?

```
foreach(ListViewDataItem question in unansweredQuestions)
{
    ((Label)question.FindControl("lblMissingField")).Text = "*";
}
```

I've made that the unansweredQuestions are only those ListViewDataItems that I want, and still am suprised to see the output HTML sets all of them to "*"...?

I've also tried Setting `Visible = true` instead of setting the Text to '*' (which was my original preference) without any luck.

Going a little mad here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have needed to do functionality similar to what you are doing and the updates / checks were done server side, I have implemented a DataBinding method for each control I want to customize.  When something changes, I rebind to my model with the bits and pieces updated that need to be changed.

So for example in your case assume I am binding to an list of objects (could be DataTable or whatever) that has the following details:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
public List<MyData> listOfMyData = GetListOfMyData();
```

Then my databinding event on the label would be implemented

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMissingField" runat="server" OnDataBinding="lblMissingField_DataBinding" />
```

Then the implementation of the databinding:

```
protected void lblMissingField_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(sender);
    lbl.Text = (Eval("Answer").ToString() == string.Empty) ? "*" : string.Empty;
}
```

This gives you a lot of control on every single item in your template.  Instead of dealing with all your controls after your data is loaded, this lets you have the data modified as the data is being bound.

I know it's not a solution to your exact question but maybe just a suggestion of another way to approach the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've implemented something similar and it works really well.  I've tried for too many hours trying to figure out what the issue was the other way - it just doesn't make sense.